# How to get contents of php page in a child popup

Tags: php, html

I have a `signup.php` page located at http://nexushost.uni.me/signup.php

I want to get all of that including the register button on the signup popup located on this page http://nexushost.uni.me.

Sorry, let me clarify:
I want the contents of the signup.php page
in the form on the **home page** sign up popup

### So signup.php contents ---> home page signup popup

Okay this is the bottom line I basically what the form on the signup.php page does on the signup button.
So if you sign up on signup.php page, you can see that it says that you will receive an activation email shortly
How do I get that form action on my signup popup.
Sorry I was not specific the first time

Comment: I don't understand, you mean you want the HTML code?

Comment: Did you tried something already?

Comment: Sorry none of these answers is what I wanted. I hope you can understand the clarified question and I am greatly sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I answered my own question just copied and pasted form html from signup.php to this page. Although the verification code is static I can live with that. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

**Body:**

`<li><a href="#Signup" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</a></li>`

`<div id="Signup" class="modal hide fade LoginSignup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">`
Enter what you wat to show here*
`</div>`

And you need to get these 4 tags: (`modal hide fade LoginSignup`) and copy them from the http://nexushost.uni.me//css/hosting.css file, and maybe do some changes to them.

Or do you want to call the pop up window with a JavaScript function?